# Removing spaces from column

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I found tons of articles stating you can remove spaces like this:

```
update mytable set Name=TRIM(Name)
UPDATE mytable SET Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(Name))
```

My columns is nvarchar have I misunderstood something, because my column names still have spaces in start and end of the values like below:

'Der_j_McD '

Comment: Perhaps those spaces are something other than regular spaces.  Even ASCII has a number of different whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below;

1. Find any special characters like char(10), char(13) etc in the field value.
2. Check the status of ANSI_PADDING ON. Refer this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql) article.

Try

```
UPDATE Table SET [Column] = REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM([Column])),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
```

Comment: Also Take the 'char(160)-non breaking space' for the consideration while doing like this.Came up with the same scenario few days before and the root cause is due to non breaking space.